# Create tibble from list elements in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, tibble

So I have this list of lists and inside each list I have elements that are vectors of equal lengths and a single value in one element. I want to create a tibble of the vectors and store the tibble in the list of lists.

```
> neighbours
$p1
$p1$course_names
 [1] "X1"  "X2"  "X3"

$p1$course_capacities
 [1] 1 1 1 

$p1[[2]]
[1] 4.123106

$p2
$p2$course_names
 [1] "X1"  "X2"  "X3"

$p2$course_capacities
 [1] 1 1 1 

$p2[[2]]
[1] 4.123106
```

Final output should look like this:

```
> neighbours
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   course_names course_capacities
   <chr>                    <dbl>
 1 X1                        1.00
 2 X2                        1.00
 3 X3                        1.00

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 4.123106

[[2]]
[[1]][[1]]
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   course_names course_capacities
   <chr>                    <dbl>
 1 X1                        1.00
 2 X2                        1.00
 3 X3                        1.00

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 4.123106
```

I guess I'd prefer a tidyverse solution since I am looking for tibbles. Of course, I am happy to consider any approach.

Answer (score 0):

its not a great structure but there are two ways. First off I have tried to recreate your initial list:

```
neighbours <- list(p1 = list(
                         list(course_names = c("X1","X2","X3"),
                              course_capabilities = c(1,1,1)),
                         4.123106
                         ),
               p2 = list(
                         list(course_names = c("X1","X2","X3"),
                                 course_capabilities = c(1,1,1)),
                         4.123106
                         )
)
```

then either use lapply() or purrr::map()

```
neighbours %>% purrr::map(~list(as_tibble(.[[1]]),.[[2]]))
```

or

```
lapply(neighbours, function(p){
  list(as_tibble(p[[1]]), 
       p[[2]])
})
```